# How do I print out a dictionary from a list of dictionaries after I pulled data from an API?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have pulled data from an API and I successfully saved it to a json file as a list of dictionaries. But, now I would like to print out each dictionary from that list of dictionaries.

Doing:

```
for i in my_data_file.json:
    print(i)
```

does not work. In fact it prints out as the following:

```
[
{
a
:
some data
}
,
{
b
:
some data
}
```

I would like it to print like the following:

```
{a: some data}
{b: some data}
```

so each dictionary is printed on a separate line. I know something like this possible becuase if I try to do the following:

```
list_dict = [{'a': 12}, {'b': 34}, {'c': 56}]

for i in list_dict:
    print(i)
```

it prints out the following:

```
{'a': 12}
{'b': 34}
{'c': 56}
```

which is exactly what I want. Is there something I am missing fundamentally in order to achieve this with my JSON file?

Comment: Is `my_data_file.json` a string?

Comment: No, just a plain list of dictionaries

Comment: Exactfile contents might help then

Comment: It seems like your data is corrupted... you even tried yourself list of dicts... and it worked fine..
The problem might be on different part of your code.. Your data look exactly like you did just split in it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you stored the file as `my_data.json`,

```py
import json

with open("my_data.json") as json_file:
    json_list = json.load(json_file)

    for dictionary in json_list:
        print(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON to pretty-print JSON with indentation.

```
import json
sample=[{'a': 12}, {'b': 34}, {'c': 56}]
new= {}
for d in sample:
    new.update(d)
print(json.dumps(new,indent=4))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can read the json first, with the `json` library. like this,

```
import json 

with open("data.json") as file1: 
    data = json.load(file1)
    
    for i in data: 
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON files are written and read back in using `json` package

from your example:

```
list_dict = [{'a': 12}, {'b': 34}, {'c': 56}]

# dump the list_dict to list_dict.json file
with open('list_dict.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(list_dict,fp)

# read it back in
with open('list_dict.json','r') as fr:
    list_dict_readin=json.load(fr)
```

Here the new variable `list_dict_readin` wll be same as original variable `list_dict`.